# Facebook login PHP: URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings

Tags: php, facebook, redirect, oauth, parse-server

I'm using **Parse Server** to log in with Facebook on my website, but of course, I have all the code for Facebook PHP SDK to handle login, and it was working fine until a few days ago.
'
This is the error I get while trying to login:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not
>   whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. 
>       Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

My Facebook Login settings:
[image]

This is my **fb-callback.php** script:

```
<?php
require_once 'fb-autoload.php';
include 'Configs.php';
// include 'fbconfig.php';

$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
  'app_id' => $_GLOBALS["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"],
  'app_secret' => $_GLOBALS["FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET"],
  'default_graph_version' => 'v2.3',
  ]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();

if (isset($_GET['state'])) {
    $helper->getPersistentDataHandler()->set('state', $_GET['state']);
}


try {
  $accessToken = $helper->getAccessToken();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
  // When Graph returns an error
  echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
  echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
  exit;
}

if (! isset($accessToken)) {
  if ($helper->getError()) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo "Error: " . $helper->getError() . "\n";
    echo "Error Code: " . $helper->getErrorCode() . "\n";
    echo "Error Reason: " . $helper->getErrorReason() . "\n";
    echo "Error Description: " . $helper->getErrorDescription() . "\n";
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request');
    echo 'Bad request';
  }
  exit;
}

// Logged in
// echo '<h3>Access Token:</h3>';
// var_dump($accessToken->getValue());

// The OAuth 2.0 client handler helps us manage access tokens
$oAuth2Client = $fb->getOAuth2Client();

// Get the access token metadata from /debug_token
$tokenMetadata = $oAuth2Client->debugToken($accessToken);
// echo '<h3>METADATA:</h3>';
// var_dump($tokenMetadata);


// Validation (these will throw FacebookSDKException's when they fail)
$tokenMetadata->validateAppId($_GLOBALS["FACEBOOK_APP_ID"]); // Replace {app-id} with your app id
// If you know the user ID this access token belongs to, you can validate it here
//$tokenMetadata->validateUserId('123');
$tokenMetadata->validateExpiration();

if (! $accessToken->isLongLived()) {
  // Exchanges a short-lived access token for a long-lived one
  try {
    $accessToken = $oAuth2Client->getLongLivedAccessToken($accessToken);
  } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
    echo "<p>Error getting long-lived access token: " . $helper->getMessage() . "</p>\n\n";
    exit;
  }

  //echo '<h3>Long-lived</h3>';
  //var_dump($accessToken->getValue());
}

$_SESSION['fb_access_token'] = (string) $accessToken;

// User is logged in with a long-lived access token.
// You can redirect them to a members-only page.
// header('Location: login.php');

// CHECK IF SESSION IS OK, GET GRAPH OBJECT AND GO BACK TO login.php
if (isset($_SESSION)) {

  $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name', $accessToken);
  $node = $response->getGraphNode();

  // Get ID, Name and Email of Facebook user
  $fbid = $node->getField('id');         // To Get Facebook ID
  $fbfullname = $node->getField('name'); // To Get Facebook full name
  $femail = $node->getField('email');    // To Get Facebook email ID
  // $token = $session->getToken(); // Get Access Token
  $token = $_SESSION['fb_access_token'];


  // ---- Session Variables -----
  $_SESSION['FBID'] = $fbid;
  $_SESSION['FULLNAME'] = $fbfullname;
  $_SESSION['EMAIL'] =  $femail;
  $_SESSION['TOKEN'] = $token;


// ---- GO TO fb-login.php ----
header("Location: fb-login-confirm.php");

} else {
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
?>
```

I don't know if I have to edit/add something else, as I said above, my FB login was working smoothly until a few days ago.

Comment: The actual value of the redirect_uri parameter in your login dialog call uses the www version of your domain, but in your settings you put it without the www.

Comment: thanks so much @CBroe, it worked!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was pretty simple, my URL was missing **www** in the **Valid OAuth redirect URIs** field:

```
 https://www.example.com/woopy/fb-callback.php
```